go with modules does not find github.com/andelf/go-curl but finds others
I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
yendtj@tacs:~/workspace/tacsnet3$ uname -a
Linux tacs 6.5.0-28-generic #29~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Apr  4 14:39:20 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
yendtj@tacs:~/workspace/tacsnet3$ 

yendtj@tacs:~/go/pkg/mod/github.com$ env | grep GO
GOBIN=
GOROOT=/usr/local/go
GO111MODULE=on
GOPATH=
yendtj@tacs:~/go/pkg/mod/github.com$ 


GOPATH is not set so it should be using the modules from go.mod.
When I go build, I get
yendtj@tacs:~/workspace/tacsnet3$ go build cmd/main/main.go 
# command-line-arguments
cmd/main/main.go:12:11: undefined: curl.GlobalInit
cmd/main/main.go:12:27: undefined: curl.GLOBAL_ALL
yendtj@tacs:~/workspace/tacsnet3$ 

My main.go program is trivial:
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    curl "github.com/andelf/go-curl"
    jwt "github.com/golang-jwt/jwt/v5"
)

func main() {
    var err error

    _ = curl.GlobalInit(curl.GLOBAL_ALL)

    _, err = jwt.Parse("ccc", func(t *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) { return nil, nil })

    fmt.Printf("Fail to read ini file: %v", err)
}


my go.mod is:
module testmodulename

go 1.22

require (
    github.com/andelf/go-curl v0.0.0-20200630032108-fd49ff24ed97
    github.com/golang-jwt/jwt/v5 v5.2.1
)

Files appear to be in the correct place:
yendtj@tacs:~/workspace/tacsnet3$ ls -l  ~/go/pkg/mod/github.com/
total 24
drwxrwxr-x 3 yendtj yendtj 4096 May  4 16:19 andelf
drwxrwxr-x 3 yendtj yendtj 4096 May  4 08:39 davecgh
drwxrwxr-x 3 yendtj yendtj 4096 May  4 08:39 go-ini
drwxrwxr-x 4 yendtj yendtj 4096 May  4 16:49 golang-jwt
drwxrwxr-x 3 yendtj yendtj 4096 May  4 08:39 pmezard
drwxrwxr-x 3 yendtj yendtj 4096 May  4 08:39 stretchr
yendtj@tacs:~/workspace/tacsnet3$ ls -l  ~/go/pkg/mod/github.com/andelf/
total 4
dr-xr-xr-x 4 yendtj yendtj 4096 May  4 15:39 go-curl@v0.0.0-20200630032108-fd49ff24ed97
yendtj@tacs:~/workspace/tacsnet3$ ls -l  ~/go/pkg/mod/github.com/andelf/go-curl@v0.0.0-20200630032108-fd49ff24ed97/
total 148
-r--r--r-- 1 yendtj yendtj  1609 May  4 15:54 callback.go
-r--r--r-- 1 yendtj yendtj   129 May  4 15:39 callback.h
-r--r--r-- 1 yendtj yendtj  1043 May  4 15:39 c-callback.c
-r--r--r-- 1 yendtj yendtj 22105 May  4 15:39 compat.h
-r--r--r-- 1 yendtj yendtj 26001 May  4 15:54 const_gen.go
-r--r--r-- 1 yendtj yendtj  5274 May  4 15:54 const.go
-r--r--r-- 1 yendtj yendtj  2822 May  4 15:54 core.go
-r--r--r-- 1 yendtj yendtj   646 May  4 15:55 core_test.go
-r--r--r-- 1 yendtj yendtj 15520 May  4 15:55 easy.go
-r--r--r-- 1 yendtj yendtj  1578 May  4 15:55 easy_test.go
dr-xr-xr-x 2 yendtj yendtj  4096 May  4 15:39 examples
-r--r--r-- 1 yendtj yendtj 11357 May  4 15:39 LICENSE
-r--r--r-- 1 yendtj yendtj  1170 May  4 15:55 logging.go
-r--r--r-- 1 yendtj yendtj  1683 May  4 15:55 logging_test.go
dr-xr-xr-x 2 yendtj yendtj  4096 May  4 15:39 misc
-r--r--r-- 1 yendtj yendtj  4422 May  4 15:55 multi.go
-r--r--r-- 1 yendtj yendtj    79 May  4 15:39 NOTICE
-r--r--r-- 1 yendtj yendtj  1575 May  4 15:39 README.md
-r--r--r-- 1 yendtj yendtj  1500 May  4 15:55 share.go
yendtj@tacs:~/workspace/tacsnet3$ 

I see the function I am calling in the curl package:
yendtj@tacs:~/go/pkg/mod/github.com$ grep GlobalInit andelf/go-curl@v0.0.0-20200630032108-fd49ff24ed97/*.go
andelf/go-curl@v0.0.0-20200630032108-fd49ff24ed97/const.go:// for GlobalInit(flag)
andelf/go-curl@v0.0.0-20200630032108-fd49ff24ed97/core.go:func GlobalInit(flags int) error {
yendtj@tacs:~/go/pkg/mod/github.com$

I was expecting the curl go package to be found.  Note that the IDE (Intellij) set for go modules does not see any syntax errors, so it must find the curl code.  In fact auto completion sees the go functions.

I don’t see any error about not finding the curl package. Do you have a C compiler and libcurl installed?

cmd/main/main.go:12:11: undefined: curl.GlobalInit
cmd/main/main.go:12:27: undefined: curl.GLOBAL_ALL  Both of these errors during compile because the module is not found.  These are compile errors long before linking.

Don’t use filename arguments on go build.

If the module was not found, you would not get compilation errors. Go resolves dependencies first.

Perhaps my problem title was not correct.  Maybe it should have been "why is go not finding members in github.com/andelf/go-curl".  As far as filename arguments, if I leave off the filename, I get "no Go files in ...".  If I cd down to the source and run go build with no filename specified, it finds my go file and displays the same error as reported in the problem.

That curl package is just a wrapper around libcurl, so it requires libcurl and a C compiler (and cgo must of course be enabled). Do you have those requirement installed?

I will be putting an answer.  Installing c and pkg-config were the answer, but you mention cgo enabled, which it must have been.  How does one enable cgo as I would like to include this in my answer for a complete answer for others.

As mentioned in the comments, the solution was to install the c compiler, pkg-config and the curl dev library.  curl was already installed.
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev

sudo apt-get install gcc
sudo apt-get install pkg-config

cgo must be enabled, but I do not know how to control cgo.  It must be on in my environment for this to have worked.
Thanks.
